# jQuery contains() with a variable syntax

Tags: javascript, jquery, syntax

I have an "uncaught exception: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: )" in a jQuery application.

The code is:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){                      
        $('.drag').click(function() {
           $('.drag').each(function(i) {
                $(this).addClass('test' + i)
            });  

           var vtxt = $(this).text();
           $("p").removeClass("on");
           $("p:contains("+ vtxt +")").addClass("on");

       });
    });
```

The problem is when I add the variable vtxt to a contains:
**$("p:contains("+ vtxt +")").addClass("on");**

I've tried several quotes but it just does not work.
What is the right syntax for adding a variable to a contains?

Comment: What's the value of `vtxt`. It might contain brackets.

Comment: This isn't jQuery related per se. It's your JavaScript input to contains() that is syntactically incorrect. :)

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Try this:

```
$("p:contains('" + vtxt + "')").addClass("on");
```

Comment: vtxt does not contains brackets.
Andrew's response gave me a valid syntax, it works now.

Thank you!

Comment: make sure you you escape the vtxt contents as it will fail if it ever contains the **'** or **"** character ..

Comment: How should I escape the vtxt?

Comment: With backslashes. Or just loop over all `p` elements filtering for `p.text().indexOf(vtxt)!==1`. This avoids the escaping issue and is no slower than the selector version, since it's a non-standard selector jQuery has to implement in the same sort of way itself.

Comment: If this answer is fit your needs you can accept it, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, thank you for your support. I am new to jQuery and still learning the basics.

Thank you.

Answer (score 9):

Old question, but I must leave a note for future generations. Andrew's answer (the accepted one) didn't work for me. What **did** work was using a pre-made string as selector. Borrowing OP's examples:

```
var selector = "p:contains("+ vtxt +")";
$(selector).addClass("on");
```

Comment: Agee!  Accepted answer did also not work for me. This one does! (2021)

Answer (score 3):

I have used this answer in order to solve a similar problem.
I want to prevent the use of `"` and `'`

When using `$("p:contains('" + valor + "')").addClass("on");`, it **works**.

But when using `$('p:contains('" + valor + "')**'**).addClass("on")`, it **does not**!