# jquery :contains selector using variable

Tags: jquery, contains

Why is it that using variable within :contains() doesn't work? Is there any way to make it work? `filter('contains()')` didn't work either.

```
<h2>Test</h2>
<div>Test</div>

var model = $('h2').text();
//variable doesn't work
$('div:contains(model)').css('background','yellow');
//obviously, string works
$('div:contains("Test")').css('background','yellow');
```

Comment: Duplicated: See answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2191419/jquery-contains-with-a-variable-syntax

Comment: Has nothing to do with text nodes, JS doesn't parse variables inside strings (looks like you may be used to PHP?) You'll have to use `$('div:contains('+$modele+')').css('background','yellow');`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unlike PHP, Javascript does not support string interpolation.

If you want to use a variable inside a string, you must **concatenate** it using the `+` operator.

Answer (score 13):

Selectors doesn't use Javascript variables. You have to put the value from the variable in the selector string:

```
$('div:contains("' + $modele + '")')
```

Answer (score 5):

it just a concatenation issue:

```
$('div:contains(' + $modele + ')').css('background','yellow');
```

Answer (score 1):

as stated in @Slaks answer you need to concatenate.

```
$('div:contains('+$modele+')').css('background','yellow'); works
```

here is a fiddle to it.

http://jsfiddle.net/CMKsF/

Answer (score 1):

you need to pass it as string .. so concatenate the var with `"` using `+` operator.. so that it takes it as string

try this

```
var $modele = $('h2').text();
//variable doesn't work
$('div:contains("'+$modele+'")').css('background','yellow');
```