# how to use $(this) with foreach in javascript using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on a personal project in Javascript to allow people to create a table of "dream plays" in Scrabble.  Here is the link: http://psyadam.neoclaw.net/tables8.html

I am currently trying to allow the user to edit a dream play.

Here is my code:

```
function editRow(e)
{
    var eventEl = e.srcElement || e.target, 
    parent = eventEl.parentNode
    parent = parent.parentNode
    var test = $(parent.cells[0]).text()
    $('tr').each(function(){
        $(this).children("td:contains(test)").each(
            function()
            {
                pageEnd.innerHTML += "success"
                $(this).addClass('selected')
            }
        )
    })
    pageEnd.innerHTML += test
    //pageEnd.innerHTML += $(parent.cells[3]).text()
    insertRow()
}

// insertRow assumes that the correct row in the table has the "selected" class added to it
function insertRow()
{
    var Row = $('<tr>').append(
        $('<td>').append('<input id="input1">'),
        $('<td>').append('<select id="input2"><option value=""></option><option value="Yes">Yes</option><option value="No">No</option></select>'),
        $('<td>').append('<select id="input3"><option value=""></option><option value="Natural">Natural</option><option value="1 Blank Used">1 Blank Used</option><option value="2 Blanks Used">2 Blanks Used</option></select>'),
        $('<td>').append('<select id="input4"><option value=""></option><option value="vs Computer">vs Computer</option><option value="Online Game">Online Game</option><option value="Friendly Game">Friendly Game</option><option value="Club Game">Club Game</option><option value="Tournament Game">Tournament Game</option></select>'),
        $('<td>').append('<input id="input5">')
    )
    $("#myTable tr.selected").after(Row)
}
```

Right now I'm just trying to get my code to insert a row into the table.  I am trying to do this by using the code `$(this).addClass('selected')` to tag the row the user selected and then use it in my insert function to insert a row.  However, nothing seems to happen.  I am using `pageEnd.innerHTML += "success"` as a debugging tool to see if it is even getting there.  Unexpectedly, it prints success twice when it should only print once, as in the test I ran every word was unique.

In any case I can't figure out why it's not working.  Any help is appreciated.  Thanks, ~Adam

Comment: Could you add small working code snippet on http://jsfiddle.net?

Comment: The `this` inside the nested `.each` callback is not the same as the one in the outer `.each`.  Also, `.children` isn't a valid function call.

Comment: shouldn't you show inputs and dropboxes instead of editing the text alignement

Comment: `var that = $(this);` .. or something

Comment: When I try your page, it gets an error that `$("#myTable tr.selected").textAlign` is not a function. `textAlign` is a DOM property, not a jQuery method.

Comment: And in the code in your question, `$(this).children` should be `$(this).children()` -- everything in jQuery is a function.

Comment: The line in the code "$(this).textalign" should have been "$(this).addClass('selected')".  My apologies, this was just something I was trying to see if I could get any attribute to work.  I edited the original question and that has been fixed.

Comment: I don't think your `contains` selector is going to function the way you intend for it to.  Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2191419/jquery-contains-with-a-variable-syntax

Comment: @Barmar, yes that was something I was trying as a debug measure.  I think that should be fixed now.

Comment: @David Oh, do I need to do it like this: $(this).children("td:contains('" + test + "')").each(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two options to achieve this:

The first one as the others are suggesting i.e. by keeping a variable of outer `this` and then using this:

```
$('tr').each(function() {

     var outerThis = this;
     // inside another loop (not sure about children method, just an example)
     $(outerThis).children("td:contains(test)").each(function() {
          // do something with outerThis to operate on further
     });
});
```

Another option to use Javascript's `bind()` method:

```
$('tr').each(function(i, trElement) {
     // this == trElement

     // inside another loop
     $(outerThis).children("td:contains(test)").each(function(index, tdElement) {
          $(this) // will be now tr element
          $(tdElement) // will be td element
     }.bind(this));
});
```

Comment: Success!  I just had to make sure I had $() around outerThis and also change $(this).addClass('selected') to $(outerThis).addClass('selected').  Thank you for all your help!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function editRow(e) {
    var eventEl = e.srcElement || e.target, 
    parent = eventEl.parentNode
    parent = parent.parentNode
    var test = $(parent.cells[0]).text()
    $('tr').each(function(){

        var outerThis = this;

        outerThis.children("td:contains(test)").each(
            function()
            {
                pageEnd.innerHTML += "success";

                $(this).children().css('text-align', 'center');
            }
        )
    })
    pageEnd.innerHTML += test
    //pageEnd.innerHTML += $(parent.cells[3]).text()
    insertRow()
}
```

I set the outer `this` to a variable which you can use. Also `textAlign` is not a jQuery function. You need to use `.css()` and then specify `text-align` in that.

Comment: I tried that, and I get this error: TypeError: outerThis.children is not a function
outerThis.children("td:contains('" + test + "')").each(