# how to dynamically pass a variable in 'options:contains' in jQuery to get the value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to get value of a select tag's option by text. when I am putting the variable, it is not getting any value. But when I am giving the text manually in single quote it is working. But I want this to be dynamic.

This works fine:

```
var value = $("#someId").find("option:contains('sometext')").val()

alert("value: "+value) // this works fine
```

but this does not:

```
var textVar = 'sometext'

var value = $("#someId").find("option:contains(textVar)").val()

alert("value: "+value) // this doesn't work fine
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery contains() with a variable syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2191419/jquery-contains-with-a-variable-syntax)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do like this:

```
var textVar = 'sometext';

var value = $("#someId").find("option:contains(" + textVar  + ")").val();

alert("value: " + value);
```