# Where each variable is equal to spans content add class

Tags: javascript, jquery

**The Question and Codes**

I am struggling with the below code:

```
$('.rdsubs-mysubscriptions table tbody tr td a').each(function() {
  var subItem = $(this).html();
  //console.log(subItem);
  var subItemStripped = subItem.substring(12);
  console.log(subItemStripped);
  $('body').find('span:contains("subItemStripped")').addClass('HELLO');
}); // end of each function
```

When I check the console for `subItemStripped` then it shows this:

```
Framework
Content
Slideshow
```

Which means (in my head at least ;-)) that for each `span` that is inside the `body` it should find one of these `subItemStripped` and where it finds a match it should add the class `hello` but this is not happening.
Actually, nothing is happening.

When I change this line:

```
$('body').find('span:contains("subItemStripped")').addClass('HELLO');
```

to

```
$('body').find('span:contains("Framework")').addClass('HELLO');
```

It works nicely. So am I putting the variable `subItemStripped` wrongly in there or has it something to do with the `.each()` function.

**I tried the below things to make it work**

With the above code I tried a couple of variations before I came here:

```
$('body').find('span:contains(subItemStripped)').addClass('HELLO');

$('body').find("span:contains('subItemStripped')").addClass('HELLO');
```

I also tried it with completely different sets of code I gathered from other SO posts but none of those worked. Why I don't know.

```
$("span").filter(function() {
  return $(this).text() === subItemStripped;
}).addClass("hello");

$("span").filter(function() {
  return $(this).text() === subItemStripped;
}).css("font-size", "6px");
```

**Why do I need this**

I know I don't have to explain why I need this but it could be useful in coming up with other great ideas if the above is not feasible.

I have a webpage and on that page is a menu filled with products that a user can download if he/she has access.
Each menu item has a span with the title in it. Those titles are built up like: `Framework` `Content` `Slideshow`

On this same page is also a component that shows all the users subscriptions.
With the above code, I look to all the subscriptions of the user. Which returns
`CompanyName Framework` `CompanyName Content` `CompanyName Slideshow`

Then I Strip `.substring(12)` all the parts that I know are not present inside the menu. Which leaves me with `Framework` `Content` `Slideshow`

At this point, I know that some menu titles and the stripped item are the same and for every match, I want to add a class upon which I can then add some CSS or whatnot.

Hopefully, the question is clear and thanks to everyone in advance for helping me out.

Comment: Because subItemStripped is a variable you need to change to: $('body').find('span:contains("' + subItemStripped + '")').addClass('HELLO');

Comment: Can you post your HTML file so we can test your code

Comment: @gaetanoM Is correct, however your usage of `filter()` should have solved the problem. Check that `subItemStripped` holds the value you are expecting it to

Comment: @gaetanoM You are completely right. Right after I posted the question I came on this site: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2191419/jquery-contains-with-a-variable-syntax

And found the answer which is the same as you are saying!

`$('body').find("span:contains('" + subItemStripped + "')").addClass('HELLO');`

Thanks so much!

Comment: @RobKwasowski Thank you for your response, fortunately, it is already solved so no need to post more code.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan The filter was also the first thing I did it seemed to me to be the winner and the correct way forward. And I checked the `subItemStripped` and it holds the values correctly but the filter was just not filtering. So I went another way. Thank you for your response!

Comment: Perhaps try `return $(this).text().trim() === ... `

Comment: @gaetanoM Can you make your comment in an answer? Then I can select it as the accepted answer.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Thank you for your suggestion you are talking about the filter function right?

Comment: Yep, that's right

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192055/discussion-between-purple11111-and-rory-mccrossan).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@gaetanoM You are completely right. Right after I posted the question I came on this site:
[jQuery contains() with a variable syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2191419/jquery-contains-with-a-variable-syntax)

And found the answer which is the same as you are saying!

```
$('body').find("span:contains('" + subItemStripped + "')").addClass('HELLO');
```

Thanks so much!

@gaetanoM Can you make your comment in an answer? Then I can select it as the accepted answer. I am answering this question now just to make sure it has an answer. As people get punished for asking questions that don't get answers.

Comment: Off discussion but you could write the same line of code with the es6 template literal so it can be much more readable: $('body').find(`span:contains('${subItemStripped}')`).addClass('HELLO'); Notice there are backticks(the symbol above tab) around the string.